# View is not appearing correctly after clicked the search button in toolbar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Trying to open a second tab in bottom navigation bar with click event.
Click is happening in the firstview toolbar searchview.
when i trying to click search button, its not moving to second view.
But if i try to click normally it working perfectly. the view problem only appearing when i click search view only. can anyone help me.

EDIT:
in other words i have enabled searchview in the toolbar. if i click search view in the keyboard it will call (onQueryTextSubmit) method. in this method i need to switch the fragment. (means if am in the homefragment, if i clicked the search button it should redirect to dashboard fragment)

MainActivity

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //loading the default fragment
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;

        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```
````

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("your title");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
                return true;
            }

        });
    }


}
```

DashboardFragment.java

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    public DashboardFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, null);
    }
}
```

fragment_Dashboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
</LinearLayout>
```

these are the images of the views.

[image]

[image]

Comment: add Dashboard fragment and layouts of both

Comment: @GaneshPokale i have edited it please take a look

Comment: Add SearchView code in parent activity

Comment: @GaneshPokale Have look at homefragment. I have enabled searchview in toolbar.

Comment: your toolbar is in activity or fragment

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement you `searchView` implementation in your  Mainactivity as 
follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //loading the default fragment
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;

        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
                return true;
            }

        });


 searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                //here whenever you click on searchview you will redirected to dashboard fragment 
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DashBoardFragment())
                .commit();
    }
});
    }

}
```

Try this way. I hope it will work for you

Comment: @ios newbie try this

Comment: i think you got my question wrong.
i have enabled searchview in the toolbar. if i click search view in the keyboard it will call (onQueryTextSubmit) method know. in this method i need to switch the fragment. (means if am in the homefragment, if i clicked the search button it should redirect to dashboard fragment)..

Comment: @iosnewbie you have implemented your searchview in home fragment when you direct to dashboard fragment your searchview will not work

Comment: really sorry about that. BTW how can i call toolbar. which means what how can i add the toolbar name instead of (your_toolbar). bcz i dont have seperate toolbar. its a theme toolbar, which was created in the initial app build.

Comment: ok your not using toolbar basically your using default actionBar.  you have to implement your search logic in mainActivity

Comment: thank you bro. i'll update it and let u know. thanks for the help.